# What is Location in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to know what variable Blender uses to determine location. Something like position_x = 0 or something? I dunno.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109984/how-to-get-global-object-location-python

Answer (score 1):

You can access an object by calling it in the collections (= all things stored in 'bpy.data') 
For example:

```
import bpy

cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
```

You can search in the console for things you can access from there, like the attributes of the object: i.g. type `bpy.data.objects["Cube"].` in the console and press <kbd>SPACE</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and it will show you all the attributes and methods of this object. One of these is `location`.

So to get an objects location:

```
cube_loc = bpy.data.objects["Cube"].location
```

or to set an objects location:

```
bpy.data.objects["Cube"].location = (1,1,1)
```